media3.exoplayer on first playback starts at 2x speed for 10 seconds then normalizes
I'm writing a program in Kotlin Jetpack Composition that plays audio files from the Internet. For this I use the Media3 Exo Player library. when the audio file starts to play, at the beginning it seems to be in a hurry and is played at a higher speed, after a few 10-15 seconds, let’s say the speed returns to normal. I can’t understand why it gets this way. Below is the code for my player initialization:
ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
    .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes, true)
    .setHandleAudioBecomingNoisy(true)
    .setTrackSelector(DefaultTrackSelector(context))
    .build()

I tried changing the emulator, I tried it on a real device, the result was the same. I wanted to set such a parameter but did not find this parameter
exoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters(PlaybackParameters(1.0f))

